# Can OS X users get locked on OS X similar to on ubuntu when using git?

Tags: macos, permission, git

I have gitlab connected to my mac but when I do `git push -u origin master` I get 'Permission denied. Please try later' message which is what pops up when the user gets locked it seems.

But here in this [**post**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315377/ssh-error-permission-denied-please-try-again) users have used usermod in linux to unlock the user. I need to do something similar. Or if there is any other solution

Comment: What versions of git and OS X are involved?

Comment: its OS X 10.8.3. And I dont know what the gitlab hosted server is using. Is it something that can be fixed from myside or need a systems person to unlock me on their server?

Comment: It's not clear what troubleshooting you'll need to do to narrow down the permission error. You might try `sudo` git push to rule out a permission error on your end, but if you are an admin user on the Mac, you shouldn't be locked out and would normally be prompted to authenticate rather than getting a simple permission denied error.

Comment: I just did sudo git push from myside. It adds a RSA key fingerprint & then asks again for git@gitlab<adfdad> password which fails. So I guess it might be on server side?

Comment: Sounds like a good place to start. Also, the logs on the server side might also be illuminating as to where the permission error lies. You can also check your console on the Mac end. Sorry I don't have a direct answer.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21180249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to delete the entry from `known_hosts` file on my MAC(client) to remove the traces of old config for that particular gitlab server. And also I regenerated my ssh keys back which seemed to work! :)

I used githubs awesome [**article**](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) to regenerate the ssh-keys.